# How to modify input while typing and make Blazor see the changes

Tags: javascript, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have an input element. I added some filtering and modifying the text while typing using JavaScript `keydown` and `keypress` events.

For example - when an input accepts upper case characters, when you press just "a" (no shift, no caps lock), you get "A".

This works, however input value binding doesn't work at all. I just call `preventDefault()` on the JS event and that's it, binding is broken.

I tried to dispatch the event myself. I dispatched newly created `KeyboardEvent` and `CustomEvent` with type "change". Nothing works. I can modify input value in JS event handler, I see the changes in browser, however my C# doesn't.

How can I make this work? Do I have to invoke C# manually to update the binding, or is there another way?

The code should work just on latest Chrome / Firefox browsers, older browsers may be unsupported.

Comment: If all you are doing is capitalisation, why not use CSS to change the visual and alter the value in C# to get uppercase? To answer your question, you can dispatch a new event but without seeing what you have tried it's hard to say why it didn't work for you. Can you show your code for the input markup and the JS?

Comment: I don't need my text to just look capitalized, I need it to be really replaced, as the data in some fields of my form must be upper case. My code is a component with optional text filter, allowing custom patterns, any upper / lower case conversions and such. I tried the approach with replacing text on server-side, but it's far from optimal, and what's most important - slow. For now I'm choosing updating the binding via JS interop.

Answer (score 6):

Why don't you do in in Blazor code? In you markdown:

```
<input type="text" @bind-value="MyParamenter" @bind-value:event="oninput" >
```

and in code

```
private string myParameter;

private string MyParameter
{
    get => myParameter;
    set
    {
        myParameter = value.ToUpper();
    }
}
```

Comment: Because it's slow and breaks things. The element has external two-way binding, validation support and complicated event handling. It's a dynamic autocomplete component using Entity Framework to provide infinitely-scrolling completion list. I used JSInterop to handle binding manually and it works perfectly. Both changing case and filtering input. Probably it does exactly what the framework would do, but I have full control over it.

Comment: Blazor server-side, IMHO, is not very practical. Something line old Web Forms with huge overhead to make a stateless thing statefull. In client-side such code would be absolutely fast and would break nothing.
To avoid sending data back and forth, than, you can try to make a javascript function, that will serialize the data you need into json object and return it into Blazor through JSInerop, where it will be deserialized it into C# object. But than does not differ much from using client-side javascript framework and server-side ASP MVC Api.

Comment: Well, since I delegated mostly all visuals to components that use JS, it now saves me a huge amount of time. The most important aspect of Blazor is using WebSockets under the hood to exchange data between client and server. It's WAY much faster than AJAX. And no need for separate frontend code. Just MVC-like app. And using WebSockets directly is like writing a web app in assembly or C. Also: ALL business logic in C#. None in JS or SQL.

Comment: But I agree, Blazor out of the box is hardly usable to create serious applications. I created my own extension of Blazor / EF Core that fixes most disturbing issues like spurious updates and lack of dynamic views in EF. I extended ComponentBase to allow components update on demand, not when the user moves a cursor over an element ;) Without blazor - I would have to create API first for fetching data as JSON, then JS to consume JSON. Now I put models directly into razor views, entities as data-sources.

Comment: @Harry I have exactly the same sentiments.  Blazor is highly productive to work in, but I would also like to eliminate spurious updates and have more control over how the system works.  Can you share your code improvements to Blazor??  Or possibly give enough detail about exactly what to do for me to make the same modifications in my own library?  Thanks!

Comment: @JamesHoux It's been quite time since I've done my big Blazor project, are you still interested? I'm not doing Blazor for a long time, but I solved most of the problems. I made an extension library that takes care of spurious updates at the cost of added complexity. I never finished the NuGet package, but maybe I should if anyone else needs it. I mean the code works on production, all it left is just share the lib (and probably write some docs for it).

Comment: @Harry if you wouldn't mind, toss it on github and post a link in your comment.  Don't worry about dressing it up a lot.  That's a lot to ask.  A lot of help would be just a brief readme file that explains the gist of how the library works and how to use it correctly.

Comment: @JamesHoux: https://gist.github.com/HTD/f056f2bc9bf9872d9212452e59332605  Here's my quick gist, I just pasted it from my production code base as is. Check the overrides. It looks like a really quick and dirty hack but it works with my crazily complicated components like real-time, data-base driven auto-complete, searchable and sortable tables with infinite scrolling. I pay for the DB traffic so spurious updates costed a lot until this fix. The full lib will be released as package as soon as I finish it. Now I'm working on some low level IoT stuff so completely no time for that.

Comment: I looked at the .cs file. It looks very good.  I think its self-explanatory for folks who understand the problem and solution.  Also, I think it *might* be overkill to make it a nuget library.  Personally, I think simple files like this work fantastic as drop-in .cs files. Having the code in your solution self-documents what's actually happening and lets you get deep into debugging if necessary.  Thanks for the post!

Comment: @Harry I just realized you're the original poster for the question.  You should put the GIST in the answer after text that says "UPDATE:" or something helpful. :)

Comment: @JamesHoux: There was a different, more relevant topic somewhere - this went far away from the original question. TBH I expected the problem with spurious updates to be fixed by now officially, but I haven't checked the status yet. Anyway, when I find more relevant question I will post it there. For now I'm glad I'm not the only one seeing a problem with Blazor data-bindings. Of course the workaround causes some troubles on its own, but they are manageable. I hope they finally fix that for good one day. BTW, I used the CSS in relevant part ;) Works well.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74416702/convert-mudtextbox-text-to-upper-case-when-typing/74417244#74417244) answers your question. In, short, when you want to handle the TextChanged event you could do something like this:

```
<MudTextField Label="Some Label Text"
              T="string"
              Value="person.FirstName"
              ValueChanged="(value) => person.FirstName = value.ToUpper()"
              Immediate="true" />
```

The "trick" is to split the `@bind-value` in two: `Value` and `ValueChanged`. Then in the `ValueChanged` you can do whatever you want with the power of C#.

Note that Blazor abstract the JS side from us, with some experience, I learned to stay away from JS side as much as possible when developing with Blazor and it saved me from a lot of headaches.