# Convert MudTextBox text to upper case when typing

Tags: blazor-webassembly, mudblazor

How can i covert MudTextBox text to upper case when typed

```
<MudTextField Required="true" Label="@languageContainer.Keys["FirstNameUS"]" Variant="Variant.Outlined" 
                                  @bind-Value="person.FirstNamesUS" For="@(() => person.FirstNamesUS)" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
<MudTextField Required="true"
              Label="@languageContainer.Keys["FirstNameUS"]"
              Variant="Variant.Outlined"
              T="string"
              Value="person.FirstNamesUS"
              ValueChanged="(value) => person.FirstNamesUS = value.ToUpper()"
              Immediate="true"
              For="@(() => person.FirstNamesUS)" />
```

[TryMudBlazor](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/ckGwbvPQMHGEVThW)